# I need a quick and dirty way to append to a text file in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, logging, text-files

I've got a very small standalone vb.net app that gets run automatically.  Every now and then it hits an error condition that I want to log and then keep processing.  But, this is far too minor a thing to store in the system's main log - I really just want to append a line to a text file.

What's the least stress way to append a line of text to a file (and have it create the file if it's not there) under .net?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[IO.File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx)(@"Y:\our\File\Name.here", "your log message here")

Comment: In what way is it dirty? It's certainly simple - but it does exactly what's required (assuming UTF-8 is okay).

Comment: w00t! This answer put me in the 5-digit club (just beat you there, Jon)

Comment: closer to 600 now- going quick

Comment: Oh, that's spectaular, and exactly what I was looking for but couldn't get MSDN to tell me about.  Also: glad I could help get into 5 digit space, Joel.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In VB.NET, [My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27t17sxs(VS.80).aspx) will do the trick. If you don't like the My namespace, [System.IO.File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) works as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is in C#, but should be trivial to change to VB:

```
    void logMessage(string message)
    {
        string logFileName = "log.file";

        File.AppendAllText(logFileName,message);
    }
```

Edited because Joel's solution was much simpler than mine =)

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Const LOG_FILE As String = "C:\Your\Log.file"

Private Sub AppendMessageToLog(ByVal message As String)
    If Not File.Exists(LOG_FILE) Then
        File.Create(LOG_FILE)
    End If

    Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(LOG_FILE)
        writer.WriteLine(message)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN article, [How to: Write Text to a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx) should do it.